# LIKE condition in SphinxQL

Tags: search-engine, sphinx

Dear programmers and IT experts, I need your help. I've just started to research what Sphinx is. I even made my own "google suggest", that fix frequent and common human search input mistakes. The problem is, that it tries to fix errors all the time and interrupt the real input.
Whell, I want the search engine try to find consilience in searched field by substring first, than, if consiliences are not found, than use my logic for fixing errors. If to say shortly, I want sphinx, first of all, execute this SQL equivalent command

```
SELECT * FROM suggest WHERE keyword LIKE('%$keyword%')
```

than, if nothing found, continue mistakes fixing.
The main questioin is....is it possible to tell spinx to search by substring?

Answer (score 2):

Sphinx can mostly do that, but need to understand how it works. Sphinx indexes individual words, and matches by keywords. It uses a large inverted index to make queries fast (rather than running a substring match)

So can do `MATCH('one two')` as a query, and it will match a document that contains '... one two ...', but the order doesn't matter, and other words can be present, so will ALSO match '... two three one ...' which wouldn't happen with mysql LIKE (its a pure substring match)

> Can use phrase operator to do that `MATCH('"one two"')`

Furthermore Sphinx matches whole words by default. So `MATCH('one two')` will only match those two works. It wont match against a document say "... one twotwentyone ...' whereas LIKE doesn't restrict to whole words.

> So can use wildcards to allow part matches. `MATCH('"*one two*"')` --- also need to enable it on the index with `min_infix_len` config!

And even more, sphinx doesn't index punctuation etc (with default `charset_table`), so a document say '... One! (two?) ... ' WOULD still match `MATCH('"one two"')`. SQL like would NOT ignore that.

> You could change sphinx to index more punctuation (via `charset_table`) to get a closer to substring match.

So `SELECT * FROM index WHERE MATCH('"*$keyword*"')` is possibly the closest sphinx query to your original (ie a substring match). Just as long as you aware of the differences. Also there is MySQL Collations to consider, they not exactly same as charset_table.

(frankly while this is correct. I wonder, if a bit OTT. If you just have a textual corpus you want to search, you could index it as normal. Then run queries though `CALL KEYWORDS()`, to get idea if the query is a valid word in the index (ie just tells you how many times given words appear in index). Can then run your algorithm to fix the mistakes)

As a side note sphinx does have a built in suggest system
http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2016/10/03/2-3-2-feature-built-in-suggests/